Is there a way to remove indentation from footnotes in the novel document class?
I'm using the novel document class for typesetting my novels in German for self-publishing with a print on-demand service. Everything works well (Thank you, @rallg, for this great package!), and I am really delighted with the outcome.
In some books, I need to enter footnotes for the translation of text in a fictitious foreign language. This also works well, but the footnotes have the same indent I set in the preamble with the \myparindent command. (Thanks for this command! It helps typesetting German novels a lot.)
I tried \noindent before and inside the \footnote command, but it had no effect.
The documentation of the novel package states:

Sorry, but even though there are numerous TeX packages for custom footnote styles, they will not work in novel. This is intentional.

Furthermore, in the file novel-Footnotes.sty of the package, I found the following code, which seems to force an indent on the footnote text:
\long\gdef\@makefntext#1{% the actual footnote, at bottom of textblock
\iftoggle{@usenomark}%
{\forceindent#1}%
{\forceindent\@getbotfnmark\,#1}%
} % end \@makefntext

Is there a way to remove this indent?
If there is no (simple) method to do this, I can let it be this way, but in the footnotes of German typeset novels, there usually are no indents. They are rather typeset with a small hanging indent.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance for your thoughts.
Here is an example to demonstrate the footnotes (the novel package is needed):
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8

\documentclass{novel}
\SetTrimSize{13.5cm}{21.5cm}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=german,babelshorthands=true,spelling=new]{german}
\SetTitle{Test Title}
\SetSubtitle{This is my Book}
\SetAuthor{Surname Name}
\SetPDFX[CGATSTR001]{X-1a:2001}
\SetChapterStartStyle{empty}
\SetChapterStartHeight{6}
\SetMargins{1.5cm}{1.7cm}{1.5cm}{1.8cm}
\SetHeadFootStyle{2}
\SetMarkerStyle[real]{number}
\myparindent{0.5cm}

\begin{document}

Es ist schwer, einen Blindtext zu finden, der den Leser nicht ablenkt, also versuche ich es gar nicht erst. Ich schreibe einfach einen kurzen Text, den der Leser lesen kann und der den Wunsch nach einem sinnvollen Text erfüllt.\footnote{Dies ist eine Fußnote, die sich hoffentlich über mehr als eine Zeile erstreckt.}

Dies ist ein neuer Absatz, der eigentlich nicht notwendig ist. Aber man kann dadurch erkennen, dass der Einzug der Fußnote die gleiche Länge hat wie der Einzug im normalen Text. 

It's hard to find a dummy text that doesn't distract the reader, so I don't even try. The Lorem-ipsum text is unsatisfactory because it makes no sense. So I just write a text that satisfies the desire for a meaningful text.\footnote{This is a footnote that should hopefully span over more than one line at the given trimsize.}

Here's a new paragraph, although I'm not sure if it's even necessary for this test. But you can see that the indent of the footnote is the same size as the normal text.
\end{document}


Try this: \makeatletter\AddToHook{cmd/@makefntext/before}{\let\forceindent\relax}\makeatother

Thanks, @hair-splitter, this did the trick. May I ask whether there would be a way to have a small hanging indent for the second and following lines of the footnote text? For example, like the footmisc package with the 'hang' option would do?

See in my answer.

The easiest way is to redefine the \@makefntext command:
\makeatletter
\long\def\@makefntext#1{%
  \iftoggle{@usenomark}%
  {#1}%
  {\@getbotfnmark\,#1}%
  }
\makeatother

The full code:
\documentclass{novel}
\SetTrimSize{13.5cm}{21.5cm}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=german,babelshorthands=true,spelling=new]{german}
\SetTitle{Test Title}
\SetSubtitle{This is my Book}
\SetAuthor{Surname Name}
\SetPDFX[CGATSTR001]{X-1a:2001}
\SetChapterStartStyle{empty}
\SetChapterStartHeight{6}
\SetMargins{1.5cm}{1.7cm}{1.5cm}{1.8cm}
\SetHeadFootStyle{2}
\SetMarkerStyle[real]{number}
\myparindent{0.5cm}

\makeatletter
\long\def\@makefntext#1{%
  \iftoggle{@usenomark}%
  {#1}%
  {\@getbotfnmark\,#1}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Es ist schwer, einen Blindtext zu finden, der den Leser nicht ablenkt, also versuche ich es gar nicht erst. Ich schreibe einfach einen kurzen Text, den der Leser lesen kann und der den Wunsch nach einem sinnvollen Text erfüllt.\footnote{Dies ist eine Fußnote, die sich hoffentlich über mehr als eine Zeile erstreckt.}

Dies ist ein neuer Absatz, der eigentlich nicht notwendig ist. Aber man kann dadurch erkennen, dass der Einzug der Fußnote die gleiche Länge hat wie der Einzug im normalen Text. 

It's hard to find a dummy text that doesn't distract the reader, so I don't even try. The Lorem-ipsum text is unsatisfactory because it makes no sense. So I just write a text that satisfies the desire for a meaningful text.\footnote{This is a footnote that should hopefully span over more than one line at the given trimsize.}

Here's a new paragraph, although I'm not sure if it's even necessary for this test. But you can see that the indent of the footnote is the same size as the normal text.
\end{document}


If you want a small indent (e.g. 5mm) from the second line in each footnote, you can use this code:
\makeatletter
\long\def\@makefntext#1{%
  \iftoggle{@usenomark}%
  {\hangindent=5mm\hangafter=1#1}%
  {\hangindent=5mm\hangafter=1\@getbotfnmark\,#1}%
  }
\makeatother



Wow, thank you, @hair-splitter! That is precisely what I was trying to accomplish. Now I can use the footnotes and all other features of the novel package for a beautifully typeset German fantasy novel with LaTeX. This is a wonderful forum. Thanks again and have a nice day.

If you found the answer appropriate, please press the accept icon. Thank you!

Oh, I'm sorry, @hair-splitter. I was not aware of the icons (small screen). Thanks for the hint.
